# Renaming multiple columns with indices in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I scraped this data from a `json` file which feeded an interactive graphic.

```
df <- structure(list(x = c("Iraq", "Syria"), Aug. = c("120", "12"), 
    Sept. = c("118", "78"), Oct. = c("184", "251"), Nov. = c("197", 
    "160"), Dec. = c("263", "169"), Jan. = c("303", "322"), Feb. = c("268", 
    "195"), March = c("304", "126"), Apr. = c("391", "145"), 
    May = c("472", "205"), June = c("407", "215"), July = c("518", 
    "371"), Aug. = c("522", "210"), Sept. = c("525", "127"), 
    Oct. = c("502", "117"), Nov. = c("530", "232"), Dec. = c("514", 
    "216"), Jan. = c("554", "170"), Feb = c("442", "218"), `March ` = c("449", 
    "132"), April = c("548", "150"), May = c("504", "178"), June = c("483", 
    "375"), July = c("332", "352"), Aug = c("259", "303"), Sept = c("291", 
    "335"), `Oct ` = c("301", "273"), Nov = c("280", "351"), 
    Dec = c("185", "318"), `Jan ` = c("234", "535"), `Feb ` = c("272", 
    "547"), Mar = c("268", "434"), `April ` = c("292", "548"), 
    May = c("267", "611"), June = c("229", "878"), `July ` = c("224", 
    "966"), `Aug ` = c("292", "1463"), `Sept ` = c("253", "1278"
    ), `Oct ` = c("196", "499"), `Nov ` = c("85", "139"), Dec = c("28", 
    "184"), `Jan 4th` = c("0", "26")), .Names = c("x", "Aug.", 
"Sept.", "Oct.", "Nov.", "Dec.", "Jan.", "Feb.", "March", "Apr.", 
"May", "June", "July", "Aug.", "Sept.", "Oct.", "Nov.", "Dec.", 
"Jan.", "Feb", "March ", "April", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", 
"Sept", "Oct ", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan ", "Feb ", "Mar", "April ", 
"May", "June", "July ", "Aug ", "Sept ", "Oct ", "Nov ", "Dec", 
"Jan 4th"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

There 's a bit more than three year of data in this data frame but only the months are given as column names. What I want to do is first renaming the colums by pasting the right year behind each month. Then transpose by using the `gather()` (that's not working right now because multiple columns have the same colnames).

I can imagine something like this:

```
df %>%
  rename(c(2:6) = paste("2014"),
         c(7:18) = paste("2015"),
         c(19:30) = paste("2016"))
```

I'm not suprised that won't work but maybe you get the gist

Comment: Perhaps solution provided below will work for you. It seems to be that there are still few columns which belong to 2017 and you need to change those using mentioned technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These steps can help you:

```
colname <- names(df)

colname[2:6] <- paste(colname[2:6], "2014")
colname[7:18] <- paste(colname[7:18], "2015")
colname[19:30] <- paste(colname[19:30], "2016")

#Now set the column name in data frame
colnames(df) <- colname


# Column names after modification
#>names(df)
# [1] "x"           "Aug. 2014"   "Sept. 2014"  "Oct. 2014"   "Nov. 2014"   #"Dec. 2014"   "Jan. 2015"   "Feb. 2015"   "March 2015"  "Apr. 2015"  
#[11] "May 2015"    "June 2015"   "July 2015"   "Aug. 2015"   "Sept. 2015"  #"Oct. 2015"   "Nov. 2015"   "Dec. 2015"   "Jan. 2016"   "Feb 2016"   
#[21] "March  2016" "April 2016"  "May 2016"    "June 2016"   "July 2016"   "Aug #2016"    "Sept 2016"   "Oct  2016"   "Nov 2016"    "Dec 2016"   
#[31] "Jan "        "Feb "        "Mar"         "April "      "May"         #"June"        "July "       "Aug "        "Sept "       "Oct "       
#[41] "Nov "        "Dec"         "Jan 4th"
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the column names of a data frame, you can do this:

```
# Example data frame
x <- as.data.frame(
    matrix(letters[1:10], nrow = 2)
    );

# Change names of columns 2-5
colnames(x)[2:5] <- paste0(colnames(x)[2:5], 1:4);
# Change all column names
colnames(x) <- paste0(colnames(x), 1:5);
```

Comment: Perhaps multiple calls to `colnames` can be avoided. But good thought.

Answer (score 1):

It may also save you a headache later if you use more standardize column names (e.g. Feb vs. Feb.). I used `lubridate` here to sequence through the dates.

```
require(lubridate)
colnames(df)[-1] <- paste(months(seq(ymd('2014-08-01'),ymd('2018-01-01'), by = 'months'), abbreviate = T), 
                          year(seq(ymd('2014-08-01'),ymd('2018-01-01'), by = 'months')))
```